# Is there any way to cast a std::any containing a derived pointer to a base pointer, without knowing the derived type?

Tags: c++, stdany

Let's say I have a `std::any` object which may or may not contain a pointer to some derived class of a given base class `B`.  Is there any way I can do something that:

1. Returns a `B *`, if the `std::any` object holds something convertible to `B *`, or
2. Throws an exception if not?

It seems like `dynamic_cast` and `std::any_cast` each provide one half of this functionality, but I don't see any way of putting the two together.

I'm aware that I can make this work in various ways that involve explicitly enumerating every type convertible to `B *`, but that's the mother of all DRY violations.

---

Sample use case:

```
std::vector<std::any> setupTools(const std::string & confFile)
{
  std::vector<std::any> myTools;

  auto conf = parse(confFile);

  for(std::string & wrenchInfo : conf["Wrenches"])
  {
    Wrench::setup(myTools, wrenchInfo);
  }    

  for(std::string & hammerInfo : conf["Hammers"])
  {
    Hammer::setup(myTools, hammerInfo);
  }

   // 25 more kinds of tools
}

Factory1::init(const std::vector<std::any> & tools)
{
  m_wrench = any_get<Wrench *>(tools);
  m_hammer = any_get<Hammer *>(tools);
  m_saw = any_get<Saw *>(tools);
}

Factory2::init(const std::vector<std::any> & tools)
{
  m_wrench = any_get<TorqueWrench *>(tools);
}

Factory3::init(const std::vector<std::any> & tools)
{
  m_saw = any_get<CordlessReciprocatingSaw *>(tools);
}
```

I don't want to include a bunch of boilerplate code listing every single kind of saw in existence just so I can grab a saw -- *any* `Saw` -- to use in `Factory1`.

Comment: Can you give some explanation as to why you need to use `std::any` for this, and what you're trying to solve overall? This sounds like a very awkward problem and there's probably a better way around it

Comment: At risk of stating the obvious, if you agree to only put `B*`s into the `std::any` object, and not derived class pointers, then that solves the problem quite easily.

Comment: @Brian: Doesn't fit my use case.

Comment: If it doesn't fit your use case then can you explain your use case?

Comment: Added sample use-case.

Comment: If all of `myTools` are tools why not just have a `Tool` base class and make `myTools` a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Tool>>`?

Comment: @AlanBirtles: That may be an option.  I'd have to go back and add a useless base-class to everything -- there is no overlapping functionality between saws and hammers -- but it seems cleaner than anything else I've found.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury: "*there is no overlapping functionality between saws and hammers*" Then why are they in the same array? There clearly is *some* logical commonality between them, because you seem to want to stick them in the same place. That is, I don't understand why `myTools` exists; why do you want to put what you claim are entirely dissimilar objects into it, then iterate over them to try to remember what you put there?

Comment: @NicolBolas: I don't gain anything by putting them in separate collections, because if I want to grab a `CordlessReciprocatingSaw` then whether I'm iterating over all the tools or all the saws I'm still iterating over a bunch of stuff that is not `CordlessReciprocatingSaw`s.

Comment: Is there no baseclass for all tools?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is unachievable. It is only possible to get an object out from `std::any` using exactly the type that was put inside. Thus, you must know the type to get anything out of it.

It seems that `std::any` does not fit your use case.

Answer (score 2):

I'm late to the party, just just came across this question looking for an answer myself.

Here's what I eventually worked out.

I needed to pass either a wxMenuItem*, or a pointer to some sort of control (all are derived from wxControl) to my function in an `std::any`. I know if I have a wxMenuItem* or a control based on flags. So ignore wxMenuItem* 's for now.

As my code only has to work with what a base class wxControl has, (and I imagine since your hammers share a common base class, you only want to do base hammer type stuff), I...

`static_cast<wxControl*>(myCombo*)`

at the calling point, and

`auto myPtr {std::any_cast<wxControl*>(theAnyField)};`

at the called point, and voila.

Comment: I imagine this has some downsides for certain use cases, but this is perfect for mine too. And, if you need to get the original type, just dynamic_cast the result of any_cast!

Answer (score 0):

Adding a base class "Tool" that has an enum ToolType attribute can help out. Then using the ToolType you can decide on the cast.

Comment: This can work, I've seen it done.  But it's a huge code smell, I would not recommend it.

Comment: Yes I agree with you, it would be better to rethink the architecture.